# Making button URL editable in Campaign Monitor custom template

Tags: campaign-monitor

I dont know why im struggling to find an answer for this as it seems like it should be a core feature?

I must have done something bad in a previous life as im having to create some email templates. Ive created my own custom HTML template as the in built builder is too limited for what i need to build.

I have added the campaign monitor tags around the sections & fields I want to be editable which all appear as editable sections when creating a campaign...ace! What I seem unable to do is add something to the  tags in the HTML to make the url editable in campaign monitor.... The email template im building is basically a list of blogs with a read more button so all the links will be different for each repeatable section.

I think I might be missing something as I cannot find any information or help on the subject, ive been googling campaign monitor custom button url, button link tag, how to make a tag visible in campaign monitor, I hate email templates, why me what did I do wrong, job boards etc etc

This is what ive been using already which works fine, but there are no examples that I can see on Campaign Monitors "help" pages for how to deal with custom urls, anyone had any experience with this or can you point me in the right direction?

```
<repeater>
         <h2>
          <singleline label="Title" repeatertitle='true' >Title</singleline>
         </h2>
         <multiline label="Article Body" >Enter the full text</multiline>
        </repeater>


<img editable src="image.jpg" width="200" label='Hero Image' />
```

Ps ive tried both adding "editable" to the  tag and surrounding the whole  tag with the  but no dice. Send help, or beer, or both!

Answer (score 1):

[Paolo Mioni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2062267/paolo-mioni) is correct, both  and  items have an add link option.

If you're setting up editable calls to action, or links that look like buttons, the best way I have found to do this is by applying inline styling to the  attribute with a dummy URL, and put a  item inside it.

```
<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com" style="display:inline-block; background:RebeccaPurple; padding:8px 22px; color:white; text-decoration:none;">
   <singleline label='Button Text'>Find out more</singleline>
</a>
```

When editing the campaign, **be careful not to remove the link**, otherwise you will lose the styling when you add the link again.

[image: Image of editable CTA in Campaign Monitor]

Comment: I can't believe Campaign Monitor still hasn't introduced an easy way to make link buttons with your own styling.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get your question correctly, but both with `<singleline>` items and images you get an "Add link" option if you click on the gear button in the box on the left. With `<multiline>` items you can add link directly in the text.

Don't worry, you didn't do anything wrong in a previous life, or at least there are people who have done worse: they are those who have to customize Wordpress themes.